# Sqlalchemy: building a class that contains a collection of items from another class

Tags: oop, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following three classes:

1. `A`
2. `AItem`
3. `ACollection`.

A user can add an unlimited amount of objects as part of `class A`. Each object that inherits from A can have an unlimited amount of objects added to it as part of `class AItem`. A user can then make collections or combinations of these items as they wish. these collections are only possibles for items that are part of `AItem` which is part of `A`. Note that, not every object in A has to have a collection and items can appear in multiple collections.

Example:

```
colors = A
red = AI(colors)
green = AI(colors)
blue = AI(colors)
yellow = AI(colors)
black = AI(colors)
brown = AI(colors)
white = AI(colors)

Collection_1 = [red, green, blue]
Collection_2 = [brown, black]
Collection_3 = [red, brown, yellow]
```

My Code so far:

```
class A(db.model):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)

    a_items = db.relationship('AItem', backref='a')

class AItem(db.model):
    __tablename__ = 'a_items'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    A_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('a.id'))

class ACollection(db.model):
    __tablename__ = 'a_collections'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

**My question:**

How can I build the `ACollection` class? Also, please feel free to "redesign" or re factor any of my code.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you start with the [Object Relational Tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html) part of SQLAlchemy documentation, which will allows you to have a better understanding of both OO concepts implemented as well as the data structures being represented. It explains Unit of Work (sessions), Domain Model and various types of relationships. If you had to read just one page (although quite a large one), this would be it.

But to get you started, see below the self-contained and running code, which has your model including many-to-many relationship, inserting, updating and deleting data. Based on your code samples code uses Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Also, I would really have given other names to both your model objects and relationships:

```
A           -> Category
AItem       -> [Category]Item
ACollection -> [Item]Collection
A.a_items   -> items (with backref *category*)
```

Below is the code, comment[ out] the line with `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO` in order to hide/see executed `SQL` statements. Just save it to some python file and run it.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
_db_uri = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = _db_uri
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True  # @TODO: uncomment to see SQL statements
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


# utility to make string representation of objects human-readable
def _repr(self):
    from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper
    attrs = class_mapper(self.__class__).column_attrs  # only columns
    # attrs = class_mapper(self.__class__).attrs  # show also relationships
    return u"<{}({})>".format(
        self.__class__.__name__,
        ', '.join(
            '%s=%r' % (k.key, getattr(self, k.key))
            for k in sorted(attrs)
        )
    )
db.Model.__repr__ = _repr


# DEFINE THE MODEL
class A(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)

    a_items = db.relationship('AItem', backref='a')

    def get_item_by_name(self, item_name):
        """ In memory search for the item of this class of given name. """
        for item in self.a_items:
            if item.name == item_name:
                return item


class AItem(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'a_items'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    A_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('a.id'))


# this table contains many-to-many relationship
t_collection_item = db.Table(
    'a_collection_item', db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column('a_items_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('a_items.id'),
            primary_key=True),
    db.Column('a_collections_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('a_collections.id'),
            primary_key=True)
    )


class ACollection(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'a_collections'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))

    items = db.relationship(AItem,
                            secondary=t_collection_item,
                            backref='collections')


def test_model():
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

        # CREATE SOME TEST DATA
        # create instance of *A*
        colors = A(name='colors')
        smells = A(name='smells')

        # add some items to them
        colors.a_items = [
            AItem(name='red'),
            AItem(name='green'),
            AItem(name='blue'),
            AItem(name='yellow'),
            AItem(name='black'),
        ]
        smells.a_items = [
            AItem(name='superb'),
            AItem(name='awful')
        ]

        # this will insert into DB instance of *A* and all their dependents
        db.session.add(colors)
        db.session.add(smells)
        db.session.commit()

        # create some collections, but first find colors
        red = colors.get_item_by_name('red')
        green = colors.get_item_by_name('green')
        blue = colors.get_item_by_name('blue')
        black = colors.get_item_by_name('black')
        yellow = colors.get_item_by_name('yellow')
        # create a new one
        white = AItem(name='white')
        colors.a_items.append(white)

        coll1 = ACollection(name='my favorites', items=[red, green, blue])
        coll2 = ACollection(name='i hate these', items=[black, yellow])

        db.session.add_all([white, coll1, coll2])
        db.session.commit()

        # SOME QUERIES
        # get collections which has blue color
        q = (db.session.query(ACollection)
            .join(AItem, ACollection.items)
            .filter(AItem.name == 'blue')
            )
        for coll in q.all():
            print(coll)
            for item in coll.items:
                print("  {}".format(item))

        # Now I hate blue, so lets remove it from my collection and rename it
        mycol = db.session.query(ACollection)\
            .filter(ACollection.name == 'my favorites').one()
        mycol.name = 'my new favorites'
        mycol.items.remove(blue)
        db.session.commit()
        assert 2 == len(mycol.items)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_model()
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want an advice of how to architecture your data or your classes? As I'm not sure, I will give you both.

**Data:**

In a data point of view, I suggest you to create a table `a_items_collections` between the tables `a_items` and `a_collections` because you have a N to N relationship (*a collection can have many items and an item can belong to many collections*). So each line of your `a_items_collections` will make a link between an item and a collection.

**OOP:**

In an OOP point of view, you have many possibilities to define your data classes. You can set an array of `AItem` in `ACollection`, you can use another collection for the table `a_items_collections`, ... You should certainly use an ORM to help you do that. I'm not an expert in Python so I cannot help you much here. Also, I would highly recommend you to separate your business classes from your data classes using an SOA (service oriented architecture) pattern. To be more clear your data classes mirror of your database should only contain properties and the intelligence to manipulate these data should be implemented in other classes (often implemented as [singleton](http://www.dofactory.com/net/singleton-design-pattern)). If you have to manipulate your collections in the same way as your items, you can take a look at the [composite](http://www.dofactory.com/net/composite-design-pattern) pattern.

Comment: It is not one or the other. If you want to do an algorithm or/and a program you should use OOP. If you want to persist the state of your item and collection objects in your program (to retrieve them when you shut down your computer or your webserver for instance), you should use a database. You may use an ORM (Object Relationnal Mapper) to help you transform your data from your database to objects (coming from what I called data classes) in your program.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The application I'm doing is a web app to get me more into web development, database design, and ORM building. This is a problem that will face me in another real world application that I plan to build, so understanding the problem and solution is crucial to me. I might have a few more questions by the end of the weekend and if you have anything to add to your answer, please feel free to do so. MY goal is to build it right and understand why it's done that way

Comment: I gave you some interesting links to follow. It could be hard to understand everything but you should take a quick look just to learn that these concepts exist. If you can do another langage than Python, PHP is better to do OOP. I would suggest you to use PHP with the framework [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/). It helps you to start your web development in an easy way, provides an ORM called Doctrine by default and could be used at an expert level when you will be more confortable with it (helping you to use all the patterns I told you).

Comment: Of course, you can ask more questions here, or directly to me if you think that it is not interesting for other people (you can find my email on my github).